# Programmatically toggle cursor visibility on X server

Tags: x11, cursor

I have a kiosk system with an X server running, hosting different graphical programs.
All programs are mutually exclusive as their systemd units conflict.
On some of those programs I want to use a native X11 cursor, such as [tcross](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/appendix/b/).
I can set it in the respective application's systemd unit via `xsetroot`.
Is it also possible to hide the cursor using `xsetroot` or another tool *without restarting the X server*?

Options I already excluded:

- `-nocursor` parameter of the X server - this disables the cursor for all applications for its entire runtime
- `unclutter` - I want the cursor to hide on the respective application during its entire runtime and not only when it is not moved.

```
[Unit]
Description=Plain X.org server
After=plymouth-quit-wait.service
Conflicts=getty@tty7.service display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/Xorg vt7 -nolisten tcp -noreset -nocursor
# Wait for server to be ready and set kiosk configuration.
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/kiosk
# Set chicken as cursor to be able to test touch screen
# and see whether X server is actually running.
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/xsetroot -cursor_name tcross
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your X11 server has the XFIXES extension (seen in `xdpyinfo`), you can write a small C program to call `XFixesHideCursor()` on the root window to hide all cursors until the program ends. You will probably need to install some X11 development packages (like `libXfixes-devel`, but it depends on your distribution) to have the include file `/usr/include/X11/extensions/Xfixes.h`. Create a file `nocursor.c` to hold:

```C
/* https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/726059/119298 */
/* compile with -lX11 -lXfixes */
/* https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/fixesproto/fixesproto.txt */
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xfixes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if(display==0)exit(1);
    int screen = DefaultScreen(display);
    Window root = RootWindow(display, screen);
    XFixesHideCursor(display, root);
    XSync(display, True);
    pause(); /* need to hold connection */
    return 0;
}
```

and compile with `gcc -o nocursor nocursor.c -lX11 -lXfixes`.
Run `./nocursor` in a suitable environment with `DISPLAY` set, and cursors
should not appear until you interrupt the program.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up writing an own Rust implementation just for the fun of it: https://github.com/homeinfogmbh/xhidecursor